# Custom authenticationFilter Spring Security 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

For a project I try to use Spring Security 3.2 as base security. Because this project is already up and running I do already have a other (own) security layer. Hence I made a custom authenticationprovider to melt the security layers. Works fine, till I also needed to make a custom anonymous authentication ([Spring Security Documentation, chapter 13](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#anonymous%20read%20here)).

So I made a custom filter and removed the orignal filter:

```
<http request-matcher="regex" use-expressions="true">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <custom-filter ref="anonymousAuthFilter" position="ANONYMOUS_FILTER"/>
    ...
</http>
```

the bean:

```
<beans:bean id="anonymousAuthFilter" class="own.package.auth.SecurityAnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="key" value="anonymousKey "/>
    <beans:property name="userAttribute" value="anonymous,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
</beans:bean>
```

and te Java Class:

```
public class SecurityAnonymousAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements InitializingBean {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.info("Entering doFilter method");
        //implementation code here
    }

    //other methods
}
```

The problem is that the doFilter method is not called when requesting the server. However the init method afterPropertiesSet() is being called... Does anyone understand why my customFilter is not fired?

P.S. I do have named the delegatingFilterProxy in the web.xml file, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Try to inject your custom filter to some other position (for example **after="ANONYMOUS_FILTER"**). May be **anonymous enabled="false"** works by filter position?

Comment: @MaksymDemidas: Thx for the comment, unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried remove **anonymous enabled="false"** ?

Comment: yes, tried the **after** both <anonymous enabled="false" /> included as excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ANONYMOUS_FILTER` is a namespace related filter. You have to avoid any namespace tag that references to the specific filter psoition:

```
   <http auto-config='false' request-matcher="regex" use-expressions="true">
    <custom-filter ref="anonymousAuthFilter" position="ANONYMOUS_FILTER"/>
    ...
   </http>
```

For further reference see the Spring security documentations in section 2.3.5: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html

Edit: And for sure leave the `<anonymous-enabled=false/>` tag.

Edit 2: Corrected my answer. This configuration should work. If not, well than we need to start looking at a bigger picture and you'd have to post more of your app, starting with the complete config.

Comment: auto-config is already at 'false' if not defined. From the documentation: _**auto-config:** Automatically registers a login form, BASIC authentication, anonymous authentication, logout services, remember-me and servlet-api-integration. If set to "true", all of these capabilities are added (although you can still customize the configuration of each by providing the respective element). If unspecified, defaults to "false"._

As said before leaving out 'anonymous-enabled=false' sadly does not work.

Comment: You were right. There was another problem that invoked it. I also had an other http tag with security=none, to make some css+js content visible to anyone. Sadly, this filter pattern was wrong and my whole app did no longer go through my anonymous filter. Thx thinking with me!